# Check if product got CustomLinkedProducts on view.phtml

Tags: magento-1, extensions, custom, related-products

I use the following extension:
https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts

But now I want to check in the file `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` if the product got CustomLinkedProducts.

I load the custom template file, by using the following code in `view.phtml`: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customlinkedproducts') ?>`

And that loads the file: `app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtm`

Inside that file there is a php check line like: `<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>`

But now I want to check in the view.phtml file if the product really got CustomLinkedProducts. What php line do I need for this?

`<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>` does not work in the view.phtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to call `<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>` in `custom.phtml`because `getItems()` method belongs to `Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Custom` block class and in `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` belongs to `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` block.

So if you want to check this in you can check it by,

```
$product = Mage::registry('product');

$itemCollection = $product->getCustomProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
    ->setPositionOrder()
    ->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($itemCollection);

$itemCollection->load();
```

Now you can check,

`<?php if($itemCollection->getSize()): ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to @Keyur Shah answer ...

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection)
```

... is [depreacted](/questions/tagged/depreacted) since **1.3.0.0.** Better use ...

```
$itemCollection->setVisibility(
   Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()
)
```

Comment: Good catch :) +1 from me thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Don't really get your point. What should I exactly change in the code of @Keyur Shah?

Comment: He changed the 1 method which is deprecated since Magento version 1.3.0.0. .Btw, which version you are using?

Comment: @KeyurShah I use https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts (1.9.3.7) and there we possibly remove deprecated methods in the future.

Comment: @HenkZ replace `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($itemCollection);` with `$itemCollection->setVisibility(...)`

Comment: @sv3n Thanks what I tought, but in that case I get a blank page. The code of @Keyur Shah works fine. I replaced only `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility') ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($itemCollection);` for  `$itemCollection->setVisibility(
   Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()
)`

Comment: Good to know it works for you :) You can accept the answer If its help you. You can accept any answer which you want :)  @HenkZ

Comment: @KeyurShah Thanks! Can you help me out with the right replacement of the code of sv3n? I can't get it right, it still displays a blank page.

Comment: @HenkZ please try this: https://gist.github.com/sreichel/e51d42cfe3f7ec79b0057732e6916f88 However, you should accept KeyurShahs answer :)